# Returning null during using SpatiaLite transformation command in Android Studio

Tags: spatialite, android

### I am using Spatialite version as following:
SPATIALITE_VERSION: 5.0.0-beta1
PROJ4_VERSION: Rel. 6.1.1
I am running the SpatiaLite `transform` function in the android studio and it returns a null value during running. I did this command in SpatiaLite GUI and the result was correct. I did another SpatiaLite command in the Android Studio and there was no error.
I think the Transform function of SpatiaLite is not recognized in the Android Studio.
This is one part of the code that gets a null value in Android Studio:
String query="select
AsText(Transform(Makepoint(37.253453454,38.253453454,4326),32632));"
complete function that I used from spatialite tutorial is as follows:

```
              public String doSimpleTransform() {
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              sb.append("Coordinate transformation...\n");
              String query="select                                  
        AsText(Transform(Makepoint(37.253453454,38.253453454,4326),32632));";
         sb.append("Execute query: ").append(query).append("\n");
              try {
         Stmt stmt = db.prepare(query);
         if (stmt.step()) {
             String pointStr = stmt.column_string(0);
            sb.append(pointStr).append("...\n");
                          }
            stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
          sb.append("Done...\n");
         return sb.toString();
           }
```

---

This is a command in Spatialite-GUI that return correct value:
SELECT AsText(Transform(Makepoint(37.253453454,38.253453454,4326),32632))

Comment: Do you have SpatiaLite available? What do you get with `select spatialite_version();`?

Comment: I am using Spatialite version as following: SPATIALITE_VERSION: 5.0.0-beta1 PROJ4_VERSION: Rel. 6.1.1 I

Comment: Perhaps there is some problem with finding the projection parameters for Transform. Proj 6 has them in a SQLite database named proj.db.

Comment: I prepared a database in Spatialite GUI desktop version and then copy this database in android and used tutorial code for an android studio. Do you think is there a missing library? Because I used a library such as a tutorial and about another function, there was no problem. But transform has a problem and is not defined. I checked the command in Spatialite GUI and even tried another Spatiallite GUI but the problem is not solved. I checked the transformation command on websites but the command is true.

Comment: Please read https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=PROJ.6 if it happens to help.

Comment: I highly appreciate you for sending tutorial .I changed the code and add new parameter using transform.Using the following code solved the error:                       query="SELECT AsText ( ST_Transform( MakePoint( 37.253453454 ,38.253453454, 4326 ) , 32632, NULL,(SELECT srtext FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid = 4326),(SELECT srtext FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid = 32632)));";

Comment: Write your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code and add new parameter using transform.Using the following code solved the error:
query="SELECT AsText ( ST_Transform( MakePoint( 37.253453454 ,38.253453454, 4326 ) , 32632, NULL,(SELECT srtext FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid = 4326),(SELECT srtext FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid = 32632)));";